# Where are the Windows Azure datacenter locations?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am looking for some sort of map to showing physical location of worldwide Windows Azure MS Data Centers.
Can you help?

Comment: I did not mean the exact location - just the general area..

Comment: You can check this link for the regions (currently 10) and the services available there - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services

Comment: Click here(http://azureping.info/) to have all the datacenters ping'd to see how close they are to you.  There are city names next to each region to give you a hint as to their location, just click 'GO'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft does not disclose the exact location of the data centres, for obvious reasons, although the internet does have some information you may have seen, such as http://matthew.sorvaag.net/2011/06/windows-azure-data-centre-locations/

Worth noting, thought, that this refers only to the 'main' Windows/SQL Azure data centres; in addition there are many CDN [nodes around the world](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/08/09/20-nodes-available-globally-for-the-windows-azure-cdn.aspx) in smaller data centres.

I am curious though - why do you ask?

Even below link will give you the location of data centers.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/regions/

Comment: Lol, this picture shows that Amsterdam is in Italy http://matthew.sorvaag.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/azure_data_centers.png but I was wondering the same as Andrew, because I always mix up west and north europe.

Comment: He was probably thinking of Athens! ;-) Those Crazy Americans!!! lolz

Comment: If you do work for the government, geographic server location may be important for legal reasons. At least that is what I infer from our legal departement.

Comment: The link http://matthew.sorvaag.net/2011/06/windows-azure-data-centre-locations/ no longer works

Comment: Azure Data Centre locations are important to answer questions such as: (1) Is my data stored in the EU (2) Is my data stored in the USA? These questions are relevant for the private sector as well as the public sector.

Comment: @Ubercoder This answers that: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/    (My interest in this is due to wanting to connect stuff with a different provider and trying to find the closest region set between providers)

Answer (score 27):

Here is a public Google Map of Azure datacenter locations - https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=214511169319669615866.0004d04e018a4727767b8&msa=0&ll=-3.513421,-145.195312&spn=147.890481,316.054688

Comment: This is more accurate than the map which matthew put online.

Comment: It needs to add Japan East+West, Australia East+Southeast, and Brazil South.

Comment: Is East US2 also in Virginia?

Comment: Completely wrong. These points are just the centers of the locations Microsoft advertises, not the actual locations of the data centers.

Answer (score 2):

The *exact physical* location of a data centre isn't usually relevant for users of applications. What's more important is the *latency* that they see when reaching the application.

But the most important thing is usually the speed of your own application.

For example, at my particular location in the UK I see somewhat better responses from the Northern Europe Azure site than the Western Europe site. This will be down to the particular route taken by packets from my PC through the local network and out to the point on the wider Internet where it peers with the Microsoft Azure systems.

If I'm dialled in through a VPN to an office in the US then I'll see better responses from a US-hosted Azure site.

However, compared to the ~60 millisecond ping time I see to the data centre, the ~200 millisecond response time from the SQL Azure queries on my site are something I can control and which are more important.

Better ways to make your Web application faster include:

- Cache, cache, cache. Use the CDN hosted versions of e.g. JQuery where possible.
- Minify your scripts and CSS, and merge if possible.
- Only perform postbacks as a last resort. Use Javascript / AJAX to load data into your application.

... all of which applies to Web applications whether they're on Azure or other hosts.

Comment: The country in which a data center resides is relevant when dealing with data sovereignty.

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten that angle. Yes, that's especially important for us here in the EU, although the PATRIOT act makes that somewhat irrelevant: see http://www.zdnet.com/blog/london/defense-giant-ditches-microsofts-cloud-citing-patriot-act-fears/1349.

Comment: Amazingly enough, I ended up at this page because we run our own CDN. And as someone running an internally maintained CDN, I can vouch that it's almost always better to use an off-the-shelf CDN if you can swing it. Fastly, CloudFlare & AWS have folks whose full-time jobs are literally tuning kernels and other low level components.

Comment: In the days of GDPR, you need to know which country houses the datacenter. For Azure, that list is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/locations/